# fetch latest value of column and shift it to top row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this function written in python. I want this thing show the latest value from a column

Here's the code

```py
def show_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=['Production', 'Forecast'])
    df['Forecast'] = df['Forecast'].shift(1)
```

And of course the output is this

```
   Production Forecast
0      274317      NaN
1      200916   330000     
2      217246   215000    
3      119830   115000     
4       66640   115000   
                 75000
```

If want add another column like `Next Forecast` that show the latest value of `Forecast` column, I add another code like this

```py
df['Next Forecast'] = df['Forecast'].tail(1)
```

And of course the output is this

```
   Production Forecast Next Forecast
0      274317      NaN           NaN
1      200916   330000           NaN
2      217246   215000           NaN
3      119830   115000           NaN
4       66640   115000        115000
                 75000
```

But I want the `Next Forecast` column take the latest value of `Forecast` before it shifted and put it on the top row like this

```
   Production Forecast Next Forecast
0      274317      NaN         75000
1      200916   330000           NaN
2      217246   215000           NaN
3      119830   115000           NaN
4       66640   115000           NaN
                 75000
```

What should I change or add to my code?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, try:

```
df.at[0, "Next Forecast"] = df["Forecast"].iat[-1]
df["Forecast"] = df["Forecast"].shift()

>>> df
   Production  Forecast  Next Forecast
0      274317       NaN        75000.0
1      200916  330000.0            NaN
2      217246  215000.0            NaN
3      119830  115000.0            NaN
4       66640  115000.0            NaN
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Production": [274317,200916,217246,119830,66640],
                   "Forecast": [330000,215000,115000,115000,75000]})
```

Comment: So I try experiment with your code and change it like `df["Forecast"] = df["Forecast"].shift(-1)`. And the result is the latest value of `Forecast` is actually moved and the latest value in the column is not 75000 anymore. What I want is the `Next Forecast` value is fetching the latest value from `Forecast` column so the 75000 is remaining there even if it's hidden. Sorry if I bother you

Comment: Your DataFrame only has 5 rows. When you use `shift()`, the last value "falls off" the frame. You first store the last value in the new column and then `shift()` like in the answer above. If that doesn't answer your question, please be more clear in your post.